# Boolean operator Arduino

Tags: c++, arduino

I'm trying to use this Arduino code and execute some lines while the VALUE is TRUE but, even if I set the VALUE to FALSE it seems that VALUE stay TRUE in void loop(). I have tried changing the IF order inside the void loop() and also replace IF statement with WHILE, all with the same results. What am I doing wrong? Any suggestion is appreciated.

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>

const char* ssid = "YOURWIFI SSID";
const char* password = "YOURWIFI PASSWORD";
boolean value = true;

void setup() {

  Serial.begin(115200);
  Serial.println();
  Serial.print("Connecting to ");
  Serial.print(ssid);

  WiFi.mode(WIFI_STA);
  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);

  //  if (static_ip) {
  //    WiFi.config(ip, gateway, subnet);
  //  }

  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(500);
    Serial.print(".");
  }
}


void reconnect() {
  Serial.print(" WiFi connected - IP address: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
  Serial.println("at the setup");
  Serial.println(value);

  if (value == true)

  {
    //
    //  DO SOMETHING REAL HERE
    //
    
    Serial.println("check before change");
    Serial.println(value);

    boolean value = false;

    Serial.println("after change to false");
    Serial.println(value);
  }
}

void loop() {
  Serial.println("just got in the loop()");
  Serial.println(value);

    if (value == false)
    {
      Serial.println("before sleep value should be false");
      Serial.println(value);
      ESP.deepSleep(0);
  
    }
    else
    {
      Serial.println("the value must be true if i got here");
      Serial.println(value);
      reconnect();
  
    }

}
```

Comment: `boolean value = false;` - this declares a new boolean variable, hiding the global one

Answer (score 0):

in line 44 boolean value = false;
this declare a local variable value and set it to false witch is not your global value

arduino suggest you use bool instead of boolean

and you should consider after wakeup from deep sleep probably your value set back to true

Comment: I will change to boolean to bool. once it wakes up should it run the script from the beginning, thus setting the value back to TRUE (line 5)?

Comment: yes if you want keep the state you need another approach probably